# a strange problem when creating an operator with Python

Tags: python, scripting, operator

My understanding of creating an operator with Python is basically this:

```
import bpy
class FOO_example(bpy.types.Operator):
    """write a tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.foo_example" 
    bl_label = "An example of Foo"

    def execute(self, context):
        #enter code here
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(FOO_example)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(FOO_example)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I get no errors, and I can run the code in the terminal by typing
`bpy.ops.mesh.foo_example()`

My problem is when I search for the operator with with the search menu (F3) I can't find it, its simply not there.

What more do I need to do to register this operator so that I can search for it with F3?

I'm using Blender_2.93.5 on Windows10.

Comment: Its works in v3.0

Comment: Thanks, but I am using an AMD video card, so I am going to wait for v3.1 which includes AMD support for Cycles.

Comment: Well I don't know if they're typos but in any case : you've got indentation problems and you actually wrote `exacute`,  not `execute`

Comment: thanks, i fixed the typo and the indentation problem here, the actual code doesn't have those problems though

Comment: I think in 2.93 they introduced a change that operators could only be found in the search operator if they were added to a menu or a panel somewhere in the interface. Apparently they went back on it in 3.0. The solution as dumb as it is, I think, is to add your operator to the layout of an existing menu

Comment: Here it works in 2.93.5. Did you activate Developer Extras in Preferences > Interface > Display?

Comment: I  have tried it both with, and without the Developer Extras enabled in Preferences.

Comment: hmm.. and we´re talking about the upper code? For example bl_options = {'INTERNAL'} in an operator prevents the search